# Recommendations for communication between Python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipc

I want to write a few python3 scripts that can retrieve almost instantly some variables (less than 400 integers in total) shared by one another.

- One script shares specific variable. Many scripts can read this variable.
- Script can update value up to 50 times per second and share up to 50 variables.
- Bus should allow at least 10k R/W operations per second.
- Bus can be managed by master process
- Hardware: ARM based board with modern Debian OS and 1GiB of RAM.
- KISS and lightweight

Some scripts are reading data from sensors and sharing their values. Some are logging values, other is processing data and sets its variables according to target motor speed.

Comment: I apologize if this comes off as harsh, but is this simply a request-list for someone to code for you? Or have you tried something first?

Comment: I’m 17 and used to take part in competitive programming only and some django stuff, so i’m noob at network programming. I’m building robot and want to write software myself. I have scripts to read data from 10+ different sensors and manage motors. Tried sqlite3 as glue but faced performance issues (maybe I should keep database in tmpfs to speed it up). Anyway i wanted to find out what more expirienced people would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend one of the following solutions:

- shared memory (have a look at python multiprocessing values/arrays)
- an HTTP server via TCP/IP or a local os socket

Comment: Since I’m not spawning scripts as subprocess is there better way of sharing memory other than using mmap module? Can You recommend mmap or unix socket based on simplicity and performance?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you any details regarding performance but both shouldn't be too complex in their respective implementation. Maybe you should spend some time and try both of them. mmap is probably going to be a lot quicker.